# Android : How to get internet connection upload speed and latency?

Tags: android, file-upload, network-programming

I want to find device network upload speed and latency, I tried FTP file uploading but didn't get success. Can anybody please help me to determine the network upload speed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I followed [this link](http://www.gregbugaj.com/?p=47) and got the almost correct download speed. And for upload speed I created a PHP api, uploaded it to FTP server and called it from device and uploaded a file. Then I calculate the time before uploading and after uploading to get Upload Speed.

Answer (score 10):

To get the current network connection type:

```
TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
int networkType = telephonyManager.getNetworkType();
```

and for the latency:

```
String host = "172.16.0.2";
int timeOut = 3000; 
long[] time = new long[5];
Boolean reachable;

for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
  long BeforeTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
  reachable = InetAddress.getByName(host).isReachable(timeOut);
  long AfterTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
  Long TimeDifference = AfterTime - BeforeTime;
  time[i] = TimeDifference;
}
```